# How to find the exact match of a string and replace in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, replace, pattern-matching, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace the words in a sentence if the word exits in "words" column with a hyperlink along with it's word and id. The table contains the column id word and sentence. Below code I got it from one of the helpful fellow mate here.Thank you.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8fe103264dc650ad4bd87b20f9c6931a

```
Create table temp(
  id       NUMBER,
  word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  Sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
);

insert into temp
SELECT 1,'automation testing', 'automtestingation testing is popular kind of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'testing','manual testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'B-number analysis','B-number analysis table' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'B-number analysis table','testing B-number analysis' FROM DUAL;

MERGE INTO temp dst
USING (
  WITH ordered_words ( rn, id, word ) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) ASC, word DESC ),
           id,
           word
    FROM   temp
  ),
  sentences ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           sentence,
           COUNT(*) OVER () + 1
    FROM temp
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               s.sentence,
               '(^|[^a-z])' || w.word || '($|[^a-z])',
               '\1' || 'http://localhost/'|| w.id ||'/<u>'||w.word ||'<u>' || '\2',
               1,
               0,
               'i'
              ),
             '(^|[^a-z])' || w.word || '($|[^a-z])',
             '\1' || w.word || '\2',
               1,
               0,
               'i'
              ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn ) 
  )
  SELECT rid, sentence
  FROM   sentences
  WHERE  rn = 1
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    sentence = src.sentence;
```

The value to be replaced is https://localhost/"id"/"word" If you see the value for id = 5 (B-number analysis) the sentence is https://localhost/6/localhost/5/B-number analysis table But the actual value is supposed to be https://localhost/6/B-number analysis table.

Current output:

```
ID   WORD                SENTENCE
1   automation testing  automtestingation http://localhost/2/<u>testing<u> 
                        is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing<u>
2   testing             http://localhost/3/<u>manual 
                        http://localhost/2/<u>testing<u><u>
3   manual testing      this is an old method of 
                        http://localhost/2/<u>testing<u>
5   B-number analysis   http://localhost/6/<u>http://localhost/5/<u>B- 
                        number analysis<u> table<u>
6   B-number analysis table http://localhost/2/<u>testing<u> 
                        http://localhost/5/<u>B-number analysis<u>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

1. First replace the strings with the ids in some wrapper that is not going to appear in your text (i.e. `testing` maps to `${2}`)
2. Then, once all the replacements have been done, replace the wrapped ids with the urls (i.e. `${2}` maps to `http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>`)

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
Create table temp(
  id       NUMBER,
  word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  Sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
);

insert into temp
SELECT 1,'automation testing', 'automtestingation testing is popular kind of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'testing','manual testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'punctuation','automation testing,manual testing,punctuation,automanual testing-testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'B-number analysis','B-number analysis table' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'B-number analysis table','testing B-number analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'Not Matched','testing testing testing' FROM DUAL;
```

**Merge**:

```sql
MERGE INTO temp dst
USING (
  WITH ordered_words ( rn, id, word ) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) ASC, word DESC ),
           id,
           word
    FROM   temp
  ),
  sentences_with_ids ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           sentence,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ordered_words )
    FROM   temp
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               s.sentence,
               '(^|\W)' || w.word || '($|\W)',
               '\1${'|| w.id ||'}\2'
              ),
             '(^|\W)' || w.word || '($|\W)',
             '\1${' || w.id || '}\2'
           ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences_with_ids s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn ) 
  ),
  sentences_with_words ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT rid,
           sentence,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ordered_words )
    FROM   sentences_with_ids
    WHERE  rn = 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REPLACE(
             s.sentence,
             '${' || w.id || '}',
             'http://localhost/' || w.id || '/<u>' || w.word || '</u>'
           ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences_with_words s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn ) 
  )
  SELECT rid, sentence
  FROM   sentences_with_words
  WHERE  rn = 1
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    sentence = src.sentence;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | WORD                    | SENTENCE                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> -: | :---------------------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | automation testing      | automtestingation http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                                                  
>  2 | testing                 | http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>                                                                                                                                                                  
>  3 | manual testing          | this is an old method of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                                                                                                
>  4 | punctuation             | http://localhost/1/<u>automation testing</u>,http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>,http://localhost/4/<u>punctuation</u>,automanual http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>-http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
>  5 | B-number analysis       | http://localhost/6/<u>B-number analysis table</u>                                                                                                                                                         
>  6 | B-number analysis table | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/5/<u>B-number analysis</u>                                                                                                                             
>  7 | Not Matched             | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e58352860296a3b6d4d52150fb69136)*

---

**Update**:

Escape any special regular expression characters in the words:

```sql
MERGE INTO temp dst
USING (
  WITH ordered_words ( rn, id, word, regex_safe_word ) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) ASC, word DESC ),
           id,
           word,
           REGEXP_REPLACE( word, '([][)(}{|^$\.*+?])', '\\\1' )
    FROM   temp
  ),
  sentences_with_ids ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT ROWID,
           sentence,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ordered_words )
    FROM   temp
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             REGEXP_REPLACE(
               s.sentence,
               '(^|\W)' || w.regex_safe_word || '($|\W)',
               '\1${'|| w.id ||'}\2'
              ),
             '(^|\W)' || w.regex_safe_word || '($|\W)',
             '\1${' || w.id || '}\2'
           ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences_with_ids s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn ) 
  ),
  sentences_with_words ( rid, sentence, rn ) AS (
    SELECT rid,
           sentence,
           ( SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ordered_words )
    FROM   sentences_with_ids
    WHERE  rn = 1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT s.rid,
           REPLACE(
             s.sentence,
             '${' || w.id || '}',
             'http://localhost/' || w.id || '/<u>' || w.word || '</u>'
           ),
           s.rn - 1
    FROM   sentences_with_words s
           INNER JOIN ordered_words w
           ON ( s.rn - 1 = w.rn ) 
  )
  SELECT rid, sentence
  FROM   sentences_with_words
  WHERE  rn = 1
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    sentence = src.sentence;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> ID | WORD                    | SENTENCE                                                                                                                                                                                                  
> -: | :---------------------- | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | automation testing      | automtestingation http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                                                  
>  2 | testing                 | http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>                                                                                                                                                                  
>  3 | manual testing          | this is an old method of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                                                                                                
>  4 | punctuation             | http://localhost/1/<u>automation testing</u>,http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>,http://localhost/4/<u>punctuation</u>,automanual http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>-http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
>  5 | B-number analysis       | http://localhost/6/<u>B-number analysis table</u>                                                                                                                                                         
>  6 | B-number analysis table | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/5/<u>B-number analysis</u>                                                                                                                             
>  7 | Not Matched             | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>                                                                                                     
>  8 | ^[($                    | http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> characters http://localhost/8/<u>^[($</u> that need escaping in a regular expression
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ba3dcec7d346ff177078326d3494c562)*

Comment: Thank you, MT0. When I run the script against the actual data, it gives me ORA-12728 invalid range in regular expression. Is there a way to print/identify which data/text is causing the issue?

Comment: @Ana Updated to escape special characters in the words.

Comment: I queried for the special characters used in the word column using 

`SELECT
     special_char,
     COUNT (*)
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT id, 
SUBSTR(word,REGEXP_INSTR (word, '[^a-z|A-Z|0-9| ]'),1) special_char
FROM temp
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (temp, '[^a-z|0-9| ]', 'i')
) temp
group by special_char;
`

I found ' : * ; + ™ – � \ _ / = % [ ? > - ( . $ , ) ! " " & @ # " ^. I will include these in the code.

Comment: @Ana You don't need to escape them all. Only the special characters for regular expressions and they should be already listed in my code.

Comment: Hi MT0, I am running this code against a table having 45k words and sentences. It's running for more than 15 hours and still running. Do you think we have to modify the code to improve the performance? Or Is there a way to identify how many rows have been updated at any given time?

Comment: Would you please check the question 58023599? It would be really great if you can help with this. I have extended your code to improve the performance and I am facing one more issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!